# Wordpress MYSQL SELECT WHERE wildcard includes NULLS

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, wildcard

My dog database contains a column "hd" containing a value between A and E or nothing if the hd rating is not known.

I'm implementing a user form for querying the database from Wordpress.

I expect most users to want to select dogs with hd ratings between A and C and I have been able to do this with:

```
WHERE hd REGEXP "[A|B|C]";
```

But there doesn't seem to be a wildcard solution with REGEXP, so if the user does not require a selection on HD I can use

```
WHERE hd LIKE "%";
```

However, if I use LIKE I can search for one hd code at a time.
eg 
    WHERE hd LIKE "B";

I have also managed to select multiple values with:

```
WHERE hd IN ('A','B','C');
```

But I can't do

```
WHERE hd IN ("%");
```

But what I really need is a selection on multiple values OR wildcard than can be passed to the SELECT statement in the $_POST array.

All suggestions welcome.

Gary

Answer (score 0):

How about using the column itself?

```
WHERE hd IN ('A','B','C')
```

or

```
WHERE hd IN (hd)
```

This will work when `hd` is not `NULL`.

An alternative might look something like this:

```
WHERE ((hd >= $hd_low and hd >= $hd_high) or $hd_low is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer myself:

```
WHERE hd IN ('A','B','C','D','E','');
```

selects all hd categories + nulls.

Users just have to delete D, E and '' from the form if they want a selection on A,B and C alone.